# Select others, then show input text in Laravel

Tags: javascript, mysql, laravel, drop-down-menu

```
<select id="position" class="form-control" name="position" onchange='checkvalue(this.value)'>
       <option value="Option A">Gedung A</option>
       <option value="Option B">Option B</option>
       <option value="Option C">Option C</option>
       <option>Other...</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="other_text" class="form-control" name="position" placeholder="Enter your location" required style='display:none' />


 <script>
    function checkvalue(val)
    {
        if(val==="Other...")
           document.getElementById('other_text').style.display='block';
        else
           document.getElementById('other_text').style.display='none'; 
    }
 </script>
```

Everything works when picking up others, but I get an error when choosing another option. Please help,, i'm newbie in laravel

[image]

This is my controller to save to database @Tran Audi
[My Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHGKR.png)

Comment: Everything is working well, what's your problem here?

Comment: Cannot save to database when i choose option like "Option A"

Comment: Add the code that you use to save the database??

Comment: That all my code in view, the problem maybe cause by same name between "select" and "input" ??

Comment: The code you provided, it worked perfectly.
So I think the problem lies in the server side code, the code that you use to save to the database.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help. i'm already attach "the code that i use to save to the database" in my edited question,, looking for your attention

Comment: your form use POST ? change $request->get() to $request->input()

Answer (score 0):

Yours:

```
<select id="position" class="form-control name="position" onchange='checkvalue(this.value)'>
```

Missing a closing speech mark

```
<select id="position" class="form-control" name="position" onchange='checkvalue(this.value)'>
```

Comment: Sure,, but this is my mistake when type this question.. actually in my code already use speech mark

Comment: My problem is can't save to database when i choose option like "Option A"